# The left-hand side of an assignment expression must be a variable or a property access in angular2

Tags: angular

I face an error saying

```
 The left-hand side of an assignment expression must be a variable or a property access.
```

With this set of code, i face that error, can anyone solve this please.

```js
 this.isDeviceType = navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)!= null ? ===  "iPad" ?
         "iOS" : navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)!= null ?=== "iPhone" ? 
         "iOS" : navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)!= null ? === 
 "Android" ? 
         "Android" : navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i)!= null ?=== "BlackBerry" ? 
         "BlackBerry" : "Browser"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are comparing an Array with a string. 
You can use `test` instead of `match`.

```js
var isDeviceType = (/iPad/i).test(navigator.userAgent) ?
  "iOS" : (/iPhone/i).test(navigator.userAgent) ?
  "iOS" : (/Android/i).test(navigator.userAgent) ?
  "Android" : (/BlackBerry/i).test(navigator.userAgent) ?
  "BlackBerry" : "Browser";

console.log(isDeviceType)
```

Comment: error TS2365: Operator '===' cannot be applied to types 'RegExpMatchArray' and 'string'.

Comment: Try '==' instead

Answer (score 0):

`String.match` delivers an array of actual matches, or null when nothing found.

So use the following pattern:

```
navigator.userAgent.match(/.../i) != null ? "..." : ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, should i include != null everywhere?

Comment: yes, as every match should be tested on not being null.

Comment: @callback's solution is better anyway.